# GMP Library: unsigned/signed arithmetics

Tags: c, gmp, integer-arithmetic

I am trying to do some computations on big numbers, using the GMP library.

I am trying to understand how could I indicate GMP to use either signed or unsigned arithmetics.

Let's say that I have two "big numbers" (i.e **mpz_t** variables): a and b. Let's say that I want to compute the multiplication a times b.

How do I specify GMP that a and b must be interpreted as signed or unsigned numbers ? For some operations, like the multiplication, GMP has only one function **mpz_mul (mpz_t rop, const mpz_t op1, const mpz_t op2)**. I was expecting to have one function for unsigned multiplication, and a second one for signed multiplication.

Thanks.

Comment: `mpz_t` is an integer type. It does integer arithmetic. It gives the mathematical result. In C signed and unsigned arithmetic exist only as means of dealing with limitations in the formats, so they overflow (with undefined behavior) or wrap. What result do you want? Do you want a result wrapped modulo some number?

Comment: Because `mpz_t` uses twos complement arithmetic, the internal representation is unsigned (e.g. 0xFFFFFFFF is -1). You handle signed integers by using the `*_si` functions (e.g. `mpz_cmp_si`) or `mpz_out_str`. Or, you could use `mpq_t` with some care.

Comment: @EricPostpischil do you mean that in C the binary representation of (signed)a*(signed)b is the same than (unsigned)a*(unsigned)b ? Also, I want both "plain" result and also the result modulo a number

Comment: @CraigEstey I guess you meant "the internal representation is signed", correct ? Also, do you mean that the cast signed/unsigned does not matter for computing arithmetic operations (+,-,*,/,%) and matters only for interpreting the result ?

Comment: Yes, the representation is always two complement (i.e. unsigned). It's only when you try to test it that the difference matters. Even for regular `int` vs. `unsigned`, the bits are the same. The difference is that for `int` the MSB is designated as the sign bit. There are different asm instructions used for `int` that implement this. Again, unsigned 0xFFFFFFF and signed -1 are the same bit pattern in the register. On x86, `cmp` it sets the flags https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register You can then conditionally jump on carry/overflow/sign as needed (e.g. sign flag = result >> 31)

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: @CraigEstey: [`mpz_t` uses sign-and-magnitude internally.](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Internals) Why do you think it uses two’s complement? Regardless, the internal implementation is not relevant for using `mpz_t`. Externally, it provides integer semantics for arithmetic. (Bitwise functions behave as if negative values were two’s complement.)

Comment: Re “How do I specify GMP that a and b must be interpreted as signed or unsigned numbers ?”: This does not make sense, and you need to clarify the question you are asking. Given two `mpz_t` items, *a* and *b*, they already have signs, and `mpz_mul` will multiply them using normal integer semantics. If you want to do something other than multiply two integers, you need to specify clearly what you want to do. Two’s complement requires specify a width in which to take the complement. `mpz_t` items are arbitrary size; they do not have a set width…

Comment: … If you want to do some modulo arithmetic, what is the modulus? What modulo operations do you want to perform?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh I think that I got it: the binary representation of a*b does not depend on the casting signed/unsigned of a and b at the hardware level, correct ?

Comment: @EricPostpischil my goal is to compute products/powers of some integers, and also to compute the result of these operations modulo another integer. These integers can be either positive or negative. For example I would like to compute (a^2 + b^3) and check if it is 0.

Comment: [GMP has functions for exponentiation and modulo exponentiation.](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, my concern was: if I take a = 0xFF for example, and compute a^3,  I would like to make sure that I get (-1)^3 and not 255^3. But if I understand now, the binary representation of the result is the same in both cases. However I'm not sure about how GMP handles and stores numbers, hence my concern

Comment: The point of an arbitrary-precision arithmetic package is to minimize or remove the limitations the numeric representation places on what computations that can be performed, especially with regard to the number of significant digits of operands and results.  Numbers can certainly be *positive*, but there is no particular value in such a system modelling C-style unsigned arithmetic directly, as this is fundamentally defined by a precision *limit*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sorry I am quite confused, here's a real example of what I would like to achieve: I have two integers a and b, which can be either positive or negative. I need to compute 4*a^3 + 27*b^2 and check if the result is 0. As a and b are "big numbers" represented by mpz_t variables, I need to store their hexadecimal representation (which can contain many many many digits) in a byte array, and export this array in these mpz_t variables (with the mpz_export function). I'm not sure how GMP will handle that.

Comment: You are thinking about this the wrong way. The internal representation used by GMP is **entirely irrelevant** to your problem. The semantics of GMP are that it takes integer inputs, it does integer arithmetic, and it gives integer outputs. If you give it a and b and ask it to compute 4•a^3 + 27•b^2, then it computes 4•a63 + 27•b^2, and it does not make mistakes because it uses two’s complement or mixes up signedness or anything else. The only mistakes you have to be concerned about in that regard are feeding the inputs to GMP correctly and getting the outputs correctly.

Comment: The input to `mpz_import` and the output from `mpz_export` are essentially just strings of bits representing a non-negative number in binary, with a choice about the order of the bytes. They are not two’s complement or signed, just plain binary. A sign can be applied after import using `mpz_get` or fetched upon export with `mpz_sgn`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see, I do not need to care how GMP is doing arithmetics, I only need to care how to properly feeding the inputs. I guess that if I feed a uint8_t array as input, I can set the number a==-1 with  [0xFF, 0xFF] and a == 1 with [0x01, 0x00]. Do you know if this method is correct (EDIT: I wrote this before seeing your last comment)? Or just import [0x01,0x00] and then use mpz_neg (based on your last comment) ?

Comment: You cannot import negative numbers with `mpz_import`. Import the absolute value and then negate it with `mpz_neg`.

Comment: You can assign an integer value of arbitrary length to an `mpz_t` via `mpz_set_str()`.  For this interface, the digits convey the *magnitude* of the number in the specified base.  Although it's not clearly documented, you can assign a negative number via this interface by preceding the first digit with a `'-'` character.  (Note: the `mpz_t` must already be initialized.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh I get it, this is perfectly clear now, thank you very much

Comment: @EricPostpischil you can write your comments as an answer if you want, I'll validate it